# State Confusion

Tags: jestjs, reducers, state-management

This code works:

```
const defaultState = {
  myProp: false
};

it('should change the value of myProp', () => {
  let state = defaultState;

  console.log(state);
  state.myProp = true;
  console.log(state)
});
```

`myProp` is successfully changed to `true`, as one would expect.

But this doesn't appear to work:

```
const myReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case CHANGE_PROP: {
      return {
        ...state,
        myProp: action.myProp
      };
    }
  }
};

const defaultState = {
  myProp: false
};

it('should change the value of myProp', () => {
  let state = defaultState;

  console.log(state);
  myReducer(state, {type: types.CHANGE_PROP, myProp: true});
  console.log(state)
});
```

I've simplified the code for this posting but the core code is there.  Simply put, `state.myProp` doesn't change.

Yet, this works:

```
expect(
  myReducer(state, {type: types.CHANGE_PROP, myProp: true})
).toEqual(
  {
    ...state,
    myProp: true
  }
);
```

So, in my unit test, why can't I change the `myProp` value and have it persist?

Answer (score 1):

I think I know where I got confused.

I can solve the problem this way

```
let newState = myReducer(state, {type: types.CHANGE_PROP, myProp: true});
```

And `newState.myProp` will definitely be `true`.

My confusion was that I assumed that `state` was being passed by reference so I thought that updating a property of it would cascade back to where it was called from.  Apparently not.

In my Context that uses this reducer is this:

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(myReducer, defaultState);
```

So I can infer that state props updated by `myReducer` return a new instance of `state` to the Context.  At least this is my assumption.